# Ayuda con Ionic y Firebase *ngFor

Tags: array, firebase, ionic, observable, push

Que esta mal en mi codigo, quiero hacer un ngFor de una variable donde por medio de un push la variable se suma para posteriormente ser un observable por la funcion asyn y wait de addToArray()

```
this.data = this.AuthService.getData()

 getData()  {

  return new Observable((observer) => {

    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      if (user) {

        this.db.database.ref("/events/5b/LaLhspwsy6cc0BM5ooFrbrF5F6j2/participants").on("value", snap => {


          this.data = [];

          this.addToArray(snap).then(result => {

            alert("then")

            observer.next(this.data)

            observer.complete()

          }) 

        }) 


       } 

     });

  })


  }


   async addToArray(snap) {

      await snap.forEach(element => {

        this.db.database.ref(`/users/${element.key}/contact`).on("value", snapshot => {

         this.data.push(snapshot.val())

         alert("foreach")

        })

      })

    return true;

  }
<ng-container *ngFor="let participant of data | async | keys">

</ng-container>
```

Comment: me da el siguiente flow:
then
foreach
foreach
 
y quiero que sea:

foreach
foreach
then

Comment: Hola Roger, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Para agregar información a tu pregunta puedes utilizar el enlace de [edit] debajo de esta